# Function pointer definition in C++ not working

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am not able to solve this error:
CODE:

```
class myClass
{
  public:
     void callMain() ;
     void (*callme)(int a , int b);

}
void myClass::callMain()
{  
        callSomeApi(callme, <some arguments>);  //callme function pointer is passed as argument
}

void (myClass :: *callme) (int a, int b)            //  it this the correct way to define a function pointer
{

}
```

I get the following error in Visual Studio 2008
error C2470:  callme looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body`

**EDIT**:
My idea:
1. i want to create member function pointer in class myClass
2. Define it outside scope.
3. Pass that function pointer as a parameter in some Api function.

Comment: what is the signature of `callSomeApi`?

Comment: (void(*)(int, int), <some more integer paramenters.>)

Comment: 1) is `myClass` singleton? 2) do the integer parameters in the call to `callSomeApi` get passed to the callback?

Comment: myClass is singleton. I did nt get ur 2nd Q??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this, but I may be wrong

```
class MyClass
{
   public:
   typedef void (*funcPtr)(int, int);
   MyClass(funcPtr whatToCall)
   { 
     callme = whatToCall;
   }
   void myClass::callMain()
   {  
       callSomeApi(callme, <some arguments>);  //callme function pointer is passed as argument
   }
private:
   funcPtr callme;
};

void f(int a, int b) {blah blah blah};


int main()
{
   MyClass myObject(f);
   myObject.callMain(); //will call the api function with f passed as argument
}
```

Comment: not exactly....i guess my Q is very clear...i want to define the function pointer like a normal Q and den pass the name of function pointer as argument to API function...how to go about that

Comment: @prap19: No, as a matter of fact, your question is not clear at all. Do you want to pass a member function as a parameter to a function which takes a plain pointer?

Comment: i have edited the Q. I guess its clear now. If not i shall elaborate more.

Comment: @prap19: I read your edit. I still don't think you need a member-function-pointer per-se! You want to pass the address of a member function to the api function, as I understand, right? If that function can be static, then it's very easy, I'll edit my answer quickly. If the function has to be nonstatic, then it's a bit harder. Tell me which way you want to go?

Comment: the api function takes void (*)(int, int) as its argument.

Comment: @prap19: I know that. We still don't manage to understand each other. Do you or do you not want to have a member function in your class which takes 2 ints and returns void and pass that function to the api function?

Comment: @armen: i would assume he does.

Comment: yes. but if i dont make that as member function pointer then it gives me conversion error like : cant convert void (*)(int, int) to (myClass::callme)(int, int). It says no such conversion

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell what you're trying to do here. Do you want to define `callme` as a method, and then pass a pointer to it as the first parameter of `callSomeApi()`? In that case, just define it as a plain old method, and type `callSomeApi(&callme, ...)` in `callMain()`: you do not need a function pointer member in your class.

If you need a function pointer as a member for whatever reason, then your declaration in line 5 is correct, and you can type `callme = &someFunction` to set the pointer to point to `someFunction()`, which would have to be defined somewhere else.

Comment: callAPI function takes parameters, and 1st parameter is the function pointer.

Comment: I get that, but do you actually need to store a function pointer in your class? Or do you just want to pass a pointer to one of your methods to `callSomeApi()`?

Answer (score -1):

it is, but why is there a body?? `callme` is a member (a function pointer).

**EDIT** i have no idea why this is downvoted.

One does not go around writing

```
int (*a)(int, int) {
}
```

because `int (*a)(int, int);` defines a variable `a` which is of type `int (*)(int, int)`.

If opener wants to use a *function* as a callback in `callSomeApi`, he needs to do

```
class myClass {
    ....
    void callme(int a, int b);
    ....
}

void myClass::callMain() { callSomeApi(&myClass::callme, this, <etc>); }

void myClass::callme(int a, int b) { ... }
```

and hope that callSomeApi accepts pmfs or function objects (and use `bind` or similar techniques)

**EDIT** for opener's changes.

a pointer to member function is a pointer. it is not a function.

To illustrate,

```
int a() { return 1; }
```

defines a function `a`. This function has type `int ()`. A function also has a function body.

However, a function pointer is defined via:

```
int (*f)();
```

In this case `f` is a function pointer. It does *not* have a function body (because it is *not* a function).

One can assign to function pointers, via `=`: `f = &a;`, or `f = a;`, for example, lets us do `f();` subsequently which will call `a`.

But basically, a function pointer doesn't have a body. Neither do pointers to member functions.

Comment: Because it doesn't :) It defines a member which is of type `int (myClass::*)(int,int);`

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: What are you referring to? `int (*a)(int, int);` defines a normal function pointer (not a pointer to member) whether or not `a` is a member of a class or not. To define a pointer to a member you would still need to use a `int (myClass::*)(int, int)` syntax even if declaring a pointer to a member that is also a member itself.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I shouldn't comment when working on something else, it always ends up badly :-/